# Workbook_Before Close Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run a code to correct the text date into Date format in the "Data" worksheet and through record macro, I recorded and it is working fine for a single column "U". How can I add it to multiple columns? (Like X, AA, AB, and AC).

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Columns("U:U").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("U1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 4), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this actually split 1 column over several? If so, you will be overwriting the next column when doing multiple. If you want to simply change text format to date format there are better ways,

Comment: just to point out that `Workbook_BeforeClose` event handler would be triggered right before the workbooks get closed whatever the "active" sheet at that time. So if you want to act on "Data" worksheet you'd better qualify your range up to worksheet reference, like `Worksheets("Data").Columns("U:U").Activate` and then and then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a method to lop through a series of columns and apply your Text-to-columns to only those columns you select (the case statement).

```
For x = 21 To 29
Select Case x
    Case 21, 24, 27, 28, 29
        Columns(x).TextToColumns Destination:=Cells(1, x), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 4), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Select

 Next x
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for your guidance. It's working fine

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually mean something like:

```
Range("X:X,AA:AC").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
```

You can specify the exact format you need for converting to date from text provided it is recognised as a date.

And as pointed out in comments, ensure you have fully qualified your range with

`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range(yourRange)`.